# Anyway to check what scheduled server reboots are?

Tags: windows-server-2016

The server reboots almost around the same time every day and `system event log 1074` says:

```
The process C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe (SERVERNAME) has initiated the shutdown of 
computer SERVERNAME on behalf of user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM for the following reason: 
Other (Planned)
    Reason Code: 0x80000000
    Shutdown Type: shutdown
    Comment:
```

Anyone know where this planned reboot is configured? I checked the windows update settings and no where it says it should install or reboot.

Comment: Check eventlog (Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational).

Comment: How do you access that @Vadim?

Comment: Try this link: [find out who restarted windows server](https://www.prajwaldesai.com/restarted-windows-server/) Is the serevr licensed? I seem to recall older versions of Windows would reboot if they weren't licensed.

Comment: @waitforit, open: Event Viewer → Applications and Services Log → Microsoft → Windows → Task Scheduler → Operational